# Como deixar o caminho das pastas relativo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Desenvolvi um projeto em ASP.NET MVC e agora estou subindo para o servidor.

Acontece que na minha máquina local, pega o endereço localhost, algo como isso:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Porém ao publicar no servidor, está lá:

www.dominio.com/meuprojeto

Então aqui começa os problemas.

tive que renomear todas as referencias para o meu javascript, css etc.

aonde estava :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Js/exemplo.js"></script>
```

eu tive que renomear para:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/meuprojeto/Js/exemplo.js"></script>
```

Há alguma outra solução sem que eu tenha que ficar renomeando tudo ?

até porque o projeto na minha máquina local agora ele se perde, e no servidor fica certo.

Comment: se você pode tirar o `/` inicial ou trocar por `./` assim ele usara o path relativo da pasta, ou seja, com sua `index` está em `www.dominio.com/meuprojeto` ao usar  **`src='./Js/exemplo.js'`** sera igual a `src='www.dominio.com/meuprojeto/Js/exemplo.js'` e localmente se sua `index` esta em `localhost:8080` ele ficara `src='localhost:8080/Js/exemplo.js'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seus links estão começando com `/` ou seja path absoluto.
Para usar path relativo a pasta atual utilize `./` ou sem a `/` inicial.

```html
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/Js/exemplo.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Js/exemplo.js"></script>
```

dessa forma ele deve funcionar igual estando tanto no `http://www.dominio.com/meuprojeto/` quanto `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

> **src começando com**:
>
> `//`: Seleção automatica de protocolo (*http , https*) exemplo de uso: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
>   `/` : Diretorio raiz
>   `./` : Diretorio atual
>   `../` : Um diretorio acima do atual, exemplo `www.dominio.com/meuprojeto/` o diretorio utilizado é o `www.dominio.com/` 
>   `../../` : Dois diretorios acima do atual (*e assim por diante*)

Comment: valeu obrigado @Icaro Martins. mas porque tem gente que não quer ajudar atrapalha negativando a pergunta ?