# Como utilizar caminho relativo em HTML usando o /

Tags: html

Olá, tenho uma duvida sobre caminho relativo em html, eu sei utilizar o (../) e (./) só que não estou conseguindo entender como utilizar apenas (/) já pesquisei varias vezes e também tentei de varias formas usar nos meus projetos e não consegui utilizar se alguém conseguir me dar um exemplo bem simples ficou muito agradecido!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como deixar o caminho das pastas relativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356207/como-deixar-o-caminho-das-pastas-relativo)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Diferença entre URLs absolutos e relativos nos conteúdos da página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2315/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-urls-absolutos-e-relativos-nos-conte%c3%bados-da-p%c3%a1gina)

Answer (score 1):

Leandro,

O `/` é o diretório raiz e, portanto, requer caminho absoluto. Isso significa que é o diretório que contém tudo! Portanto, para utilizá-lo, você precisa fornecer o caminho todo - da raiz ao arquivo em si.

Veja está [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2318/839) para mais informações sobre diretórios relativos e absolutos.

Answer (score 0):

A diferença é a seguinte:

- `/`: Diretório raiz;
- `./`: Diretório atual;
- `../`: Um diretório acima do atual, exemplo `www.dominio.com/meuprojeto/` o diretório utilizado é o `www.dominio.com/`;
- `../../`: Dois diretórios acima do atual (e assim por diante)

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que você esteja acessando o site `www.meudominio.com/dirA/dirB` sé nesta pagina existir um link para `/`  vai fazer você voltar para o `www.meudominio.com/` que é o diretório raiz, o mesmo aplica ao incluir `imagens`, `scripts` se você em uma subpasta colocar `/meuscript.js` ele vai procurar na raiz ou seja `www.meudominio.com/meuscript.js`

Outro exemplo:
Você tem uma pagina *`index.html`* dentro de `www.meudominio.com/dirA/dirB` nela você quer incluir um javascript chamado `script.js` que também esta no mesmo diretório:

Com **path absoluto** a inclusão seria assim

```
<script src='/dirA/dirB/script.js'></script>
```

Com **path relativo** a inclusão seria assim

```
<script src='./script.js'></script>
```

<sub>[Outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356220/3774) que também pode ser útil</sub>